# How can I get all div's content and append them to another div?

Tags: jquery, append

I have 2 div's.

div1 and div2. I want to get all the content from div1 and append them to div2 and then fadeOut div1.

I tried:

```
$('#div1').append('#div2');
$('#div1').fadeOut();
```

or

```
$('#div1').appendTo('#div2');
    $('#div1').fadeOut();
```

and

```
$('#div1').html('#div2');
$('#div1').fadeOut();
```

but none seems to work for me.

What Im I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with `.html()` methods is that it converts the DOM elements to HTML and vice versa. You will loose all event handlers and data bound to those elements.

Use [`.contents()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) instead:

```
$("#div1").contents().appendTo('#div2').end().fadeOut();
```

or if you want to copy the content:

```
$("#div1").clone(true, true).contents().appendTo('#div2');
$("#div1").fadeOut();
```

---

It's always helpful to read the documentation when you use methods. E.g.

```
$('#div1').append('#div2');
```

will append the string `#div2` to the element with ID `div1`. The documentation says:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

and

> **content**: DOM element, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

Similar for `$('#div1').html('#div2');`:

> **htmlString**: A string of HTML to set as the content of each matched element.

It will just replace the content of `#div1` with the string `'#div2'`.

On the other side

```
$('#div1').appendTo('#div2');
```

will append the element with ID `div1` to the element with ID `div2`:

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.

The jQuery documentation is quite good, I recommend to read it.

Comment: This will actually move the contents of `#div1` rather than just copying it, which may be fine, but probably worth mentioning. It also means the `fadeOut` may not be seen because the contents of the element has moved.

Comment: @James: The question only mentions to get the content from a to b. But well, one could use `copy` as well.

Comment: Yeah, just thought it might be worth pointing out the fact that while the visible result may be the same with this and the `html` solution, the resulting DOM will be different. However, the `contents` solution does mean the `fadeOut` may not be visible because there's nothing left in the element.

Comment: @James: You are absolutely right, it would not make sense to fade out the element if there is not content inside of it. It should work fine when cloning the node first though. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 7):

You could get the HTML of `#div1` and append that to `#div2`:

```
$("#div2").append($("#div1").html());
$('#div1').fadeOut();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gMBwy/1/).

Notice that this is similar to your third example, which didn't work because the `html` method takes a string and appends it to the selected elements. In your case, it would simply append the string literal "#div2". You need to actually get the HTML you want to append from `#div1`, and append that.

Also note that `fadeOut` simply hides the element (it sets `display:none`), and doesn't remove it from the DOM. I'm not sure if that's what you want or not.

Comment: Unless you want to replace the contents of `div2`, in which case you would replace `append` with `html`.

Comment: @nikc.org - Yes, although the question does say "append them to div2".

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div2').html($('#div2').html());
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small example for you place this below text as HTML

```
<div id="div1">
    <p>hi</p>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

and the below script

```
$("#div2").append($("#div1").html());
$('#div1').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content = $('#div1').html();
$('#div2').append(content);
$('#div1').fadeOut();
```

Comment: if we use `html()`  we would replace the content inside div2.